Use boostrap-icons for leaflet map markers
I want to use Bootstrap Icons for the map markers in Leaflet. There are a number of plugins for this (e.g. [1], [2], [3]), but they're unmaintained or don't work with the latest Bootstrap Icons.
So I tried to do this from scratch, using inline SVG rather than separate images. I took the SVG map marker "balloon" from here, and added the icon above it using absolute positioning.


const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 8);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

const icon = L.divIcon({  // leaflet default marker is 25px x 41px
  html: `
    <div>
      <svg width="25px" height="41px" viewBox="0 0 32 52" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M16,1 C7.7146,1 1,7.65636364 1,15.8648485 C1,24.0760606 16,51 16,51 C16,51 31,24.0760606 31,15.8648485 C31,7.65636364 24.2815,1 16,1 L16,1 Z"></path>
      </svg>
      <i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i>
    </div>`,
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [25/2, 41],
  className: 'icon'
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], { icon: icon }).addTo(map);
  
.icon { position: relative; }
.icon path { fill: var(--bs-primary); stroke: var(--bs-dark); }
.bi { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 4px; font-size: 1rem; color: var(--bs-light); }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" /></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div class="vw-100 vh-100 d-flex">
  <div id="map" class="flex-grow-1"></div>
</div>



The result is not as pretty (as the the library itself or as the old library plugins), but good enough... I do need to manually tweak each icon (css top / left) to fit inside the balloon.
But the marker has no shadow; do I need to do this myself or is it done via leaflet?

Here is a link to how I solved the problem with icons.
In short, each icon is built as either svg or html.
I add icons globally to html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="display:none">
  <symbol id="icon-bar" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="m17.28 19.43 ..." /></symbol>
...

And using svg inline is:
<svg fill="#ffffff">
  <use href="#icon-bar"></use>
</svg>

You can change the color, background, or even add a border to each icon.
As for the shadow, I normally add it using css.
Each icon has its own class names and a corresponding class "place-id"
All icons scale to a certain size, of course they must be prepared in the same way.
The icon can be individually changed by class in "place-id" styles, e.g. (place-69)
PS. Here I use svg symbols inline because there was no other way, but you can also use
<svg><use href="assets/img/icons.svg#icon-bar"/></svg>

That is, put all symbols in one file. There is only one problem, namely the cache of this file. Well, that's a story for another thread ;)

Thanks! Give me a chance to digest this and get back to you.
